# Edit/update existing row data in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have some data in my notepad (ID, name, surname, birthdate, etc..). I have the code to pickup the data to the userform.textboxes, but if i try to edit it and press my commandbutton, it fails. (**Error 13: Type Mismatch**)

Here is my commandbutton code to change/update the existing data:

```
Private Sub Wijzigen_Click()
Dim gegeven(1 To 10000) As personeel
Dim int_teller_n As Integer
Dim int_teller_m As Integer
Dim int_teller_p As Integer
Dim pad As String

pad = "C:\Users\fhaka\Downloads\Overzicht_Personeelsleden.txt"
int_teller_n = 1
int_teller_m = 1
int_teller_p = 1


Open pad For Input As #8

Do While Not (EOF(8))

Input #8, gegeven(int_teller_n).int_ID, gegeven(int_teller_n).str_Voornaam, gegeven(int_teller_n).str_Naam, gegeven(int_teller_n).int_Aantal_kinderen, gegeven(int_teller_n).str_Geboortedatum, gegeven(int_teller_n).str_Startdatum, gegeven(int_teller_n).str_Einddatum, gegeven(int_teller_n).str_Diploma, gegeven(int_teller_n).sng_Aantal_minuten_gewerkt, gegeven(int_teller_n).str_IN, gegeven(int_teller_n).str_UIT, gegeven(int_teller_n).str_Record


    gegeven(int_teller_n).str_IN = Now



int_teller_n = int_teller_n + 1

Loop
Close #8

Open pad For Output As #8

For int_teller_p = 1 To int_teller_n - 1
    Write #8, gegeven(int_teller_p).int_ID, gegeven(int_teller_p).str_Voornaam, gegeven(int_teller_p).str_Naam, gegeven(int_teller_p).int_Aantal_kinderen, gegeven(int_teller_p).str_Geboortedatum, gegeven(int_teller_p).str_Startdatum, gegeven(int_teller_p).str_Einddatum, gegeven(int_teller_p).str_Diploma, gegeven(int_teller_p).sng_Aantal_minuten_gewerkt, gegeven(int_teller_p).str_IN, gegeven(int_teller_p).str_UIT, gegeven(int_teller_p).str_Record
Next

Close #8

Dim int_ID As Integer
Dim str_Voornaam As String
Dim str_Naam As String
Dim int_Aantal_kinderen As Integer
Dim str_Geboortedatum As String
Dim str_Startdatum As String
Dim str_Einddatum As String
Dim str_Diploma As String
Dim sng_Aantal_minuten_gewerkt As Single
Dim str_IN As String
Dim str_UIT As String
Dim int_clear As Integer
int_pagina_grootte = 6

For int_clear = 3 To int_pagina_grootte
    Worksheets("Basisgegevens").Cells(int_clear, 1) = ""
    Worksheets("Basisgegevens").Cells(int_clear, 2) = ""
    Worksheets("Basisgegevens").Cells(int_clear, 3) = ""
    Worksheets("Basisgegevens").Cells(int_clear, 4) = ""
    Worksheets("Basisgegevens").Cells(int_clear, 5) = ""
    Worksheets("Basisgegevens").Cells(int_clear, 6) = ""
    Worksheets("Basisgegevens").Cells(int_clear, 7) = ""
    Worksheets("Basisgegevens").Cells(int_clear, 8) = ""
    Worksheets("Basisgegevens").Cells(int_clear, 9) = ""
    Worksheets("Basisgegevens").Cells(int_clear, 10) = ""
    Worksheets("Basisgegevens").Cells(int_clear, 11) = ""
Next

Open pad For Input As #4
Do Until (EOF(4))
Input #4, int_ID, str_Voornaam, str_Naam, int_Aantal_kinderen, str_Geboortedatum, str_Startdatum, str_Einddatum, str_Diploma, sng_Aantal_minuten_gewerkt, str_IN, str_UIT, str_EOR
If int_ID = CInt(UserForm_IN.TextBox1.Text) Then
    Worksheets("Basisgegevens").Cells(3, 1) = int_ID
    Worksheets("Basisgegevens").Cells(3, 2) = str_Voornaam
    Worksheets("Basisgegevens").Cells(3, 3) = str_Naam
    Worksheets("Basisgegevens").Cells(3, 4) = int_Aantal_kinderen
    Worksheets("Basisgegevens").Cells(3, 5) = str_Geboortedatum
    Worksheets("Basisgegevens").Cells(3, 6) = str_Startdatum
    Worksheets("Basisgegevens").Cells(3, 7) = str_Einddatum
    Worksheets("Basisgegevens").Cells(3, 8) = str_Diploma
    Worksheets("Basisgegevens").Cells(3, 9) = sng_Aantal_minuten_gewerkt
    Worksheets("Basisgegevens").Cells(3, 10) = str_IN
    Worksheets("Basisgegevens").Cells(3, 11) = str_UIT
End If
Loop
Close #4
Unload Me
End Sub
```

Here is my code to pickup all existing data:

```
Private Sub Getbutton_Click()
Dim id As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer, flag As Boolean
If IsNumeric(UserForm_Wijzigen.TextBox1.Value) Then
    flag = False
    i = 0
    id = UserForm_Wijzigen.TextBox1.Value

    Do While Cells(i + 1, 1).Value <> ""

        If Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = id Then
            flag = True
            For j = 2 To 7
                UserForm_Wijzigen.Controls("TextBox" & j).Value = Cells(i + 1, j).Value
            Next j
        End If

        i = i + 1

    Loop

    If flag = False Then
        For j = 2 To 7
            UserForm_Wijzigen.Controls("TextBox" & j).Value = ""
        Next j
    End If

Else
    For j = 1 To 4
    UserForm_Wijzigen.Controls("TextBox" & j).Value = ""
    Next j
End If

End Sub
```

Here are some images of my Worksheet and Userform
[image: Worksheet]
[image: UserForm]

I am able to get the requested data out, but i cannot replace/update/edit it.

I want to edit it and it should update my notepad path file aswell (which every persons data is stored on).

Comment: can u tell in wich line theres the error ?

Comment: This line gives the error.  `If int_ID = CInt(UserForm_IN.TextBox1.Text) Then`

Comment: whats the value of UserForm_IN.TextBox1.Text ?

Comment: Nothing. The textbox is there to give the ID of the person, which is in this case 7. But no specific data i think.

Comment: it seems that u are trying to convert a text string to number. check if u have e blank after or before the 7

Comment: Blanks before or after the number are not the problem, `CInt("  7   ")` will work, However `CInt("")` or `CInt("   ")` will throw error 13.

Comment: 7 in this case, is the last ID. So after 7 it is blank.

Comment: @FunThomas With `CInt (" 7 ")`, the code does not show me an error. But it does not edit my data.

Comment: @ZombieMence Can you print here the error that your are getting

Comment: Soo, in the worksheet must be an empty id, correct?